# Aptana Studio 3 require me git, why? what can I do?

Tags: php, eclipse, git, aptana, aptana3

I am following this tutorial to add code snippets to [Aptana 3 Studio](http://thomas.deuling.org/2011/09/best-way-to-add-or-edit-code-snippets-and-templates-in-aptana-studio-3/)

The problem is that when I try to click on: **‘Commands’ -> ‘PHP’ -> ‘Edit this bundle’**

Appear to me the following error message: **Requires git to clone down the bundle. Please install Git first.**

I am using Aptana 3 Studio standalone version on Ubuntu 12.04

What it exactly mean? What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What tutorial? You haven't linked to anything.

Comment: edited, tutoria link inserted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It means you require [git](http://git-scm.com), and to solve the problem, you should install git first. There are some basic instructions on how to do it on a Debian-based distribution like Ubuntu on the [Installing Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) page.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana uses Git to grab the bundles from a Git repository, probably Github.

To install Git on Ubuntu, just open a terminal and type: 
**sudo apt-get install git-core**